# sending values file and text inputs together with ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form and it has text inputs and file input for upload an image. I tried to send values to my php page but i couldnt do it. Here is my ajax codes.

```
function sendval() {
  var form = $('#user_update_form')[0];
  var form_data = new FormData();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'user_update.php',
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    success: function(msg) {
      $('#updtalert').html(msg);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: which value do you want to send to php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use FormData for ajax file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: @nevzat-uz Try `data:$("#user_update_form").serialize()` insteadof `data:form_data `

Comment: Just add `form` on this line `var form_data = new FormData(form);`.

Comment: Improved code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add from ajax inside this code

```
function sendval(){
    var form = $('#user_update_form')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData(this); 
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'user_update.php',
        processData: false,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        data:form_data,
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#updtalert').html(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I just changed var form_data = new FormData(this);  "this" to "form" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
function sendval(){
    var form = $('#user_update_form')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData(form); 
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'user_update.php',
        processData: false,
        contentType:  false,
        data:form_data,
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#updtalert').html(msg);
        }
    });
}
```